# Using VueJS with a Go backend

Tags: javascript, go, vue.js, template-engine

I want to use Go templates as well as VueJS for data-binding. Has anyone integrated both before?

I wish to use VueJS primarily for Ajax calls as doing it manually(or with jQuery) always leaves my code messy.

To be more specific, if I have a simple`<p>` tag whose value is generated from a Go template like so:

```
{{.Color}}
```

Now I want to bind to the value in
like so:

```
{{someVariable}}
```

Both are for the same tag.

Comment: Please make your question more specific

Comment: Edited the original question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are mixing Vue.js with another templating system you can choose to change the interpolating delimiters (by default`['{{','}}']`) with something else.

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}']
```

Now you can use `{{.}}` with golang and `${}` with Vue

Comment: Quick question. If I use delimiters as you specified above is there a chance for the golang templates to be parsed wrongly? Like with ${{{.Field}}}, is it possible for the parser to parse the outer two curly brackets instead of the inner two?

Comment: You mean go? No because it will look for `{{.` not `{{{`

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the Go's side you can define your own delimiters:
https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Delims